# system() calls successful from script/console but silently failing in application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, command-line, gnupg

Specifically calls to gpg.

I'm having a hard time tracking down the problem as the logs don't give any output for these failing calls and they work perfectly from the production console.

I've tried specifying the path to gpg:

```
  system "path/to/gpg --all -my --encryption -options
```

and have made sure that Passenger is running under the same user that I am entering the console as. I've also tried backticking and %x()ing the commands in search of a more verbose response.

No luck. Prayer, dance and violence have proved equally useless.

Answer (score 1):

To help debug issues like this, you could try calling a bash script which handles logging of issues, instead of the command directly:

```
#!/bin/bash
# my_gpg_script.sh

set -e
set -u
set -x
set -v

path/to/gpg --all -my --encryption -options > /var/log/whats_happening.log
```

Then call `system "my_gpg_script.sh"` from ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Lebreeze got me on the right path, but I could never get the STDOUT to redirect to my log and ended up having to debug by tracing the whole method as suggested over here https://serverfault.com/questions/98994/suppress-gpg-reading-passphrase-from-file-descriptor-0-message

```
strace path/to/gpg --all -my --encryption -options 2>>/var/log/whats_happening.log
```

It turned out to be a path issue. I had naively thought that $PATH would be the same in the console and application as long as the environment and user were the same. Not the case. Adding some extra paths in my httpd.conf file fixed me up though.

```
SetEnv PATH /this/bin:/that/other/bin:/and/dont/foget/bin
```